# how to calculate timestamp of 2 events which are irregularly spaced apart

Tags: excel, event-log

[image: sample of the data]

So I have an event log in which I would like to know the time elapsed between when a is true, and when b is false. then the timestamp difference will be calculated. I would like to know how to search the nearest previous a is true and refer to that timestamp to subtract with the b is a false timestamp. There may be an irregular number of event items in between.

as an extra requirement, I need to verify that the events are in the order:
a=true -> b=true -> a=false -> b=false

I have tried to use if statement to confirm where i have a b is false, but don't know how to search up and refer to the last previous a is true.

also, I have no clue how to verify the sequence of 4 events in a certain order.

Comment: So you want to calculate the time difference between nearest a-true and b-false? And a-true must before b-false, is it correct?

Comment: yes, exactly @Katie

Comment: Also, I wonder if your are using excel or google sheet? 'cause the result would a little different when it comes to array formula.

Comment: please post your data as https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables please update it with sample timestamps and expected results.
PS what would you expect the formula to return if there's 2 `b` FALSE values after a `a` TRUE value?

Comment: `=LET(a,FILTER(B3:B13,(C3:C13="a")*D3:D13),
      b,FILTER(B3:B13,(C3:C13="b")*NOT(D3:D13)),
INT(b-a)*24+TEXT(b-a,"u"))`

would show it in hours provided that there's as many `a` - TRUE as `b` - FALSE. But it's unclear what you really want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a supportive column to help the formula identify.

```
=C2&D2
```

And then the main formula would be:

```
=if((C2&D2)="dFALSE",(B2-ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(IF($A$2:A2="aTRUE",$B$2:B2))))*1440,"")
```

But please be notified that this method can only be used when your data is time-sequenced.

Here is the example file I created in Google Sheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/138tULefCoMdMHsOYIudugOssworU3wtzh1f7lEWelWs/edit#gid=0

If you need to use it on Excel, you may need to replace the arrayformula().